# My code is detecting directories as files and files as directories

Tags: java, android

My code is detecting directories as files and files as directories. Why is it doing that? THanks

I've attacked the full function where the issues is occuring, sorry if it's messy! Thankyou for your help again!

```
unzip(getFilesDir() + "/", "bla.zip", getFilesDir() + "/unzip/");

 public void unzip(String filepath, String filename, String unzip_path) {
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filepath + filename);

    Log.d("1st", filepath + filename);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

    try {
        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;

            String filename_temp = ze.getName();
            File fmd = new File(unzip_path, filename_temp);
            Log.d("2nd", unzip_path + filename_temp);
            Log.d("ERROR7", fmd.toString());
            //if (!fmd.exists()) {
                if(fmd.isDirectory()) {
                    Log.d("ERROR4", fmd.toString());
                    fmd.mkdirs();
                } else if (fmd.isFile()) {
                    Log.d("ERROR4", fmd.toString() +"FILE");
                }

            //} else {}
            Log.d("ERROR5", "DIR");
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(unzip_path + filename_temp);
            Log.d("ERROR6", "DIR");
            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                fout.write(bytes);
                baos.reset();
            }

            fout.close();
            //}
        }
        zis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR1", e.toString());
    }} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {            Log.d("ERROR2", e.toString());}
}

1st﹕ /data/data/au.com.amon/files/bla.zip
2nd﹕ /data/data/au.com.amon/files/unzip/docProps/
 ERROR7﹕ /data/data/au.com.amon/files/unzip/docProps
ERROR4﹕ /data/data/au.com.amon/files/unzip/docPropsFILE
ERROR5﹕ DIR
ERROR6﹕ DIR
2nd﹕ /data/data/au.com.amon/files/unzip/docProps/app.xml
ERROR7﹕ /data/data/au.com.amon/files/unzip/docProps/app.xml
ERROR5﹕ DIR
ERROR1﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/au.com.amon/files/unzip/docProps/app.xml: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
DOCUMENT﹕ docProps
```

Comment: Could `File fmd = new File(getFilesDir() + "/unzip/", filename_temp);` possibly work?

Comment: Does that file actually exist yet on disk? If not, both `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` are going to return `false`.

Comment: It's meant to get extracted from the zip file. this is the errors i'm getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense. A file *name* that is read from a ZIP file doesn't necessarily represent a file that already exists on the disk, and neither does a `File` constructed from it. So testing `isDirectory()` on it is futile, and testing it to see whether you should call `mkdirs()` is even more futile. If it was a directory you *shouldn't* call `mkdirs()`.

What you *should* be checking is `ZipEntry.isDirectory().`

Comment: oh...what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
File fmd = new File(getFilesDir() + "/unzip/", filename_temp);
```

You were using the single string arg constructor which denotes a pathname, not a filename.

Comment: To clarify, he added a comma

Comment: The difference between `new File(path+"/"+name)` and `new File(path, name)` (a) does not account for this problem and (b) is zero.